# Finding variance for a given function which is an infinite sum

Tags: variance, random-variable

I'm struggling with an expression, I'm trying to find the derivative for a given variance, with k = 1, 2,...,

[image: Function f(z) which is given]

[image: the trubbling expression]

What's really tripping me is going from the first expression of f"(z) to the second. We're adding 2 to the k variable but it's not explained. I assumed that since we have an infinite sum the two expressions are equal but I fail to see the intuition behind it and how I could explain it properly if asked so.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint:  When $k=1$ and $k=2$ what is $(k-1)(k-2)$ ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I realize now I should have developed the expression before looking for tricky substitutions.